# Google Maps Javascript API 3 Styling Geojson Icons

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My map always changes all the icons for every layer every time I have more than 1 layer on when I use 
`map.data.setStyle(function() {
   return {icon:layers.icon};
});` 
why is that? I make the call to get the Geoserver geojson URL from the database, creates multiple checkboxes based on the amount of records in the database. Then I pass the URL to another function that uses

```js
map.data.loadGeoJson(layers.url);
```

to show the layers based on which checkbox is selected. Works great when one layer is selected but if I want to turn on two layers all the icons in the map change to the last layers icon I just selected. Here is my code:

`var jsonArr = [];
 var layers = [];`

```js
    function getLayers(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "../rema/php/layers.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    $('#sidebar-layers').append('<div id="layer'+ i +'" class="checkbox" />');
                    $('#layer'+ i).append('<label id="label'+ i +'">');
                    $('#label'+ i).append('<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox'+ i +'" /><img src="img/icons/' + data[i][3] + '" style="width: 20px; height: 25px" /><h3 class="sidebar-layers-label">' + data[i][1] + '</h3>');

                    // Adds id, url and icon to a json array
                    jsonArr.push({
                        id: i,
                        url: data[i][4],
                        icon: 'img/icons/' + data[i][3],
                        layer: 'layer'+ i,
                        hidden: true
                    });
                    var thisCheckbox = document.getElementById("checkbox"+ i);
                    attachChangeListener(thisCheckbox,i);

                }       
            }
        }); 
    }

//Add the event listener to the newly created checkbox
    function attachChangeListener(thisCheckbox,i) {
        $(thisCheckbox).change(function () {
            var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
            layers = jsonArr[i];
            if (checked) {
                console.log(thisCheckbox);
                console.log(jsonArr[i].layer);
                console.log(layers.icon);

                map.data.setStyle(function() {
                  return {icon:layers.icon};
                });

                map.data.loadGeoJson(layers.url);


            }
    });
   }
```

When I select 1 layer it looks like this:
[image: One Layer turned on!]

When I select another layer the icon changes to the last selected layer:
[image: When I select more than 1 layer]

Is there a way to only set the icon for the new layer selected?

Comment: What does your GeoJSON look like?  Does it have any unique properties of the layer that could be used to determine the icon?

Comment: The 'Fire Station' Geojson only has a Name, Geom and Address Properties.... I could modify it and add a Type property and specify 'fire, school' etc? How would I modify my code then?

Comment: Change the `map.data.setStyle` function to depend on that property.

Comment: Could you create an example? I create a new GeoJson property called 'category' and added 'school' and 'firestation' as a category. I am trying to make the setStyle() dynamic to take in any value

Comment: I was able to get it working by adding `map.data.setStyle(function(feature) {
           if (feature.getProperty('category')) {
             var icon = 'img/icons/' + feature.getProperty('category') + '.png';
             return {icon: icon};
           }
            
          });`

Comment: If you want someone to create an example, you should provide some sample GeoJSON (preferably a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue. Since you figured it out, please provide an answer to your question and [accept it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) (when you can).